# Can't call custom hook from custom hook in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, azure-ad-msal

I have a React app created with `create-react-app`.

I'm trying to make a custom hook using Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL). MSAL has a custom React hook that I want to call from my own custom hook.

When I use a hook (any hook) inside my custom hook in a separate file I get this in the browser:

```
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

```js
// ourhook/index.ts

import { useEffect } from "react";

export const useMsal2 = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Hello from our hook!");
  });
};
```

```js
// app.tsx

import React from "react";
import { useMsal2 } from "./ourhook";

const App = () => {
  useMsal2();

  return <div>App</div>;
};

export default App;
```

If I call

```js
const { instance } = useMsal();
```

directly from **App.tsx** everything works fine. It only appears to be a problem if my custom hook is in its own file.

From what I see I'm not violating any hook rules. I'm calling a hook that's calling a hook, and the first call is from a top level component.

I have read other threads here about hooks in hooks, but none of them has an answer that fits this problem.

Have I missed something about hook rules, or what might be causing this?

Comment: `useMsal` hook is called in a component underneath MsalProvider

Comment: From the look of it, you're not violating any of the rules of hooks; as you say, you're calling a hook from a hook called by a component. To debug, I'd probably replace `useMsal` with some other hook for testing purposes. You've said if you use `useMsal` instead of `useMsal2` in your `App` component, it works, so I assume @MohitSharma's point above is moot, but ... Also, be sure that `useMsal` and your code are using the same instance of React.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder but wouldn't a conflict in React versions be a problem if calling `useMsal()` directly in App.tsx as well?

Comment: `useState()` inside `useMsal2()` alse generated the error message.

Comment: Try changing the name?

Comment: what do you mean? you're violating the [very first rule](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level).

Comment: I tried changing the name, but nothing. However I did find that if I created my custom hook in the same file as the component, it works. As soon as I export it from another file it stops working.

Comment: @technophyle
Docs clearly says you can call hooks from custom hooks.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level

Comment: I tried to reproduce your scenario on code sandbox, but it was working fine. Can you check below code if i have missed any thing.
https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-snow-z0lyj8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: *"`useState()` inside `useMsal2()` also generates the same error message."* Please update the question with the full `ourhook.tsx` and `app.tsx` files showing that happening (along with any changes to `tsconfig.json` etc. you're making), so that someone can do `create-react-app`, drop those files in, and see the problem. There's some problem somewhere not shown in the above.

Comment: Have you tried investigating other reasons mentioned in error message.
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: I've edited the question since the problem seems to be not with MSAL but with hooks in general.

I'm running React 18.0.0 with Typescript. It's a freshly created `create-react-app` app with nothing else in it.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I forgot that we tried to have `/ourhook` as a freestanding project and then copy pasted it into a `create react app` app.

Some of you were right, it did have its own version of react.

I'm just going to hide under a rock for the rest of the week.

Thanks for all your help! <3

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this comment just above:

```js
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";

export const useMsal2 = () => {
 // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  const { instance } = useMsal();
  const request = "";

  return {
    loginRedirect: () => console.log(""),
  }
};
```

I don't know what useMsal looks like, but from what I see, you don't actually violate any hook rule.

Comment: Nothing happens. In the updates to the post I added that even native hooks, `useEffect()` and `useState()` generates the same error, but only if the custom hook is created in a separate file.